# Why django form.as_p call form.clean method when template renders?

Tags: django, forms

I have this sample of django code:

```
# views.py
def test_view(request):
    form = TestForm(
        request.POST or { 'text': 'some text'},
    )
    data = {
        'form': form,
    }
    print 'before rendering'
    return render(request, 'test.html', data)

# forms.py
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'init'
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        print 'in clean'
```

and this template:

```
#test.html
<form id='test-form' method="post" action="some url" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

when i send get request to this file i have this output in console:

> before rendering
> init
>  in clean

when I write {{ form.text }} instead of  {{ form.as_p }} I have only:

> before rendering
> init

It seams to me that as_p method calls clean() internally in process of rendering template.
 Before that I mentioned that as_p method only is some kind of shortcut(I understand that it's a method of Form class) and doesn't realize logic.
Why does it happen? Is it a bug or some usefull feature?

Version of Django==1.5.1

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see in the source django has a _html_output helper function to return the function form.as_p(). If there is data bound to the form (like yours), then the BaseForm class property errors is called. This function calls the forms full clean. So I think this behaviour is intentionally to render form errors.

Answer (score 2):

Change your view like this:

```
# views.py
def test_view(request):

    if request.POST:
        form = TestForm(request.POST)
        # this is usually used when there's an actual post request
        # and in this block you do validation
    else:
        form = TestForm(initial={'somekey': 'somevalue'})

    data = {
        'form': form,
    }
    print 'before rendering'
    return render(request, 'test.html', data)
```

and `clean()` won't be called anymore

Comment: The essential thing to note above is the assignment to the **initial=** parameter in the TestForm constructor when the request is not made using POST. If that would have been clearly specified, this should have been marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I unproper initialize form, I should use `Form(initial={#something#})`