# Django form is being cleaned unintentionally

Tags: python, django

I have created a view that renders a template, and upon submitting the form, updates two models.

I am only validating one form for the moment (`is_valid()`), but the other form is also being cleaned, even though I have not called the `is_valid()` or `'clean()` methods on them.

My view:

```
def update_two_models_at_once(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form1 = Form1(request.POST)
        form2 = Form2(request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid():
            #form1.save()
            #post = form2.save(commit=False)
            #post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('stock:forms'))
    else:
        form2 = Form2()
    return render(request, 'update_models.html', {'form2': form2})
```

I have a print statement in `Form2` and it gets executed every time I submit the form, even though I'm trying to validate `Form1` only.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or appear to be missing? The trace back is linking back to this line here:

`return render(request, 'update_models.html', {'form2': form2})`

It appears when I first render the page, it's fine. But once I submit the page, `Form1` doesn't validate (I have purposely made it not validate), and when it renders the template again, it invokes the clean method for `Form2`. What's the go with this? I only want to validate and clean `Form1` at this time.

EDIT:

My Form2 code:

```
class Form2(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        serial = cleaned_data.get('serial')

        print(error)

    class Meta:
        model = Form2Model
        fields = '__all__'
```

Trace back once `print(error)` is reached when submitting my template:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "...\views.py", line 166, in update_two_models_at_once
    return render(request, 'update_models.html', {'form': form})
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 155, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 67, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 307, in render
    match = condition.eval(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 880, in eval
    return self.value.resolve(context, ignore_failures=True)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 676, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 802, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 843, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 174, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 377, in full_clean
    self._clean_form()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 404, in _clean_form
    cleaned_data = self.clean()
  File "...\forms.py", line 80, in clean
    print(error)
NameError: name 'error' is not defined
```

Comment: Where is the print statement exactly? And what traceback?

Comment: @DanielRoseman In my `Form2` clean method. When I intentionally throw an error, I can see where the clean method was invoked from. Which happens to be when rendering my template after failing to validate `Form1`.

Comment: Can you please show the traceback, as well as the Form2 code?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have updated my question. Let me know if you need anything else, thanks.

Comment: Since the error happens when rendering the form, I think this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471844/why-django-form-as-p-call-form-clean-method-when-template-renders, is a duplicate. If confirmed, it can be closed as such.

Comment: @Evert I've taken a look at that question but I don't know how I would implement that into my own code. Any suggestions? I've implemented the initial parameters myself, but it doesn't do anything.